# Chrome DevTools keeps breakpoints after taking them away

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having trouble clearing all the stops in my dev tools. Even after taking all the stoppers out, all my scripts keep stopping in different jquery arrays even though there's no breakpoints.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the pause icon in lower left of Sources tab is gray. You can click on it to change it's state.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you might have set "Pause on exceptions". You can change the behavior using the icon at the left bottom of the screen. More on "Pause on JavaScript exceptions" [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-exceptions_b087719962c10f94f95b29bffb37906e.frame#pause_on_exceptions).

Varunkumar Nagarajan